# C++11: Range-based for loop over range described by templated iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, iterator

In my C++03 code, I have a lot of functions that look like this:

```
class A {
public:
    template <Iterator>
    void doSomethingWithObjects(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
        for (Iterator point = begin; point != end; point++) {
            mInternal.doSomething(*point);
        }
    }
private:
    DataStructure mInternal;
};
```

I'm trying to use C++11's features as much as possible in new code, in particular the range-based for loop. My question is, how would I do this with templated iterators? Is there a magic C++ structure that takes two templated iterator types, and turns them into a range expression? In other words, I'm looking for something like this:

```
class A {
public:
    template <Iterator>
    void doSomethingWithObjects(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
        static_assert(std::is_same<Point, typename std::decay<Iterator>::type>::value, "wrong type mate!"); // extra credit
        for (auto&& point : std::magic(begin, end)) {
            mInternal.doSomething(point);
        }
    }
private:
    DataStructure mInternal;
};
```

If there is a new, preferred ways to do this kind of "add a number of objects to this structure" in C++11, I'm all ears, too.

Comment: You mean [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e2067e0122fc685) ?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Is there a `std` structure that does exactly that?

Comment: No, to my best knowledge there is nothing like that in the standard library of both C++11 and C++14

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing in the standard library. Boost has [`make_iterator_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html), a simplified version of which is trivial to write:

```
template<class Iterator>
struct iter_range {
    Iterator begin_, end_;
    Iterator begin() const { return begin_; }
    Iterator end() const { return end_; }
};

template<class Iterator>
iter_range<Iterator> make_range(Iterator b, Iterator e) { return {b, e}; }
```

---

The original question just called `push_back`. For that, it doesn't need a loop. Just use the C++03 range overload of `insert`:

```
mInternal.insert(mInternal.end(), begin, end);
```

Comment: Edited to clarify that sometimes I do calculations and so on and not only insertion.

Comment: Thanks, I use boost, so this is probably my best bet!

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class It>
struct range_t {
  It b; It e;
  It begin() const { return b; }
  It end() const { return e; }
};
template<class It>
range_t<It> range( It b, It e ) {
  return {std::forward<It>(b), std::forward<It>(e)};
}
```

then:

```
template <Iterator>
void doSomethingWithObjects(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    for (auto&& point : range(begin, end)) {
        mInternal.doSomething(point);
    }
}
```

and bob is your uncle.

"[Range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3)" is a library undergoing the standardization process that contains stuff like this already.  Boost also has similar mechanisms.

But this kind of thing is simple enough to roll your own and forget about it.  (Better versions include `empty`, conditionally support `size` and `[]`, can be constructed from containers and C arrays and anything iterable, know if they are condiguous, conditionally store a copy of the incoming container for reference lifetime extension, etc: but you don't really need any of that).

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I would add a function overload and keep the existing function around to make the transition gradual and less disruptive.

```
template <typename Container>
void doSomethingWithObjects(Container&& c) {
    for (auto&& item: c) {
        mInternal.doSomething(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! The only problem is of course if you want to pass an array, which sometimes happens in my code.

Comment: @bombax, for that use case the use of the `range_t` object suggested by the other answers will come handy.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to turn them into anything. Just use the iterators with `std::for_each`:

```
template <Iterator>
void doSomethingWithObjects(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    std::for_each(begin, end, [this](auto&& point){
        mInternal.doSomething(point);
    }

    // C++11 version
    std::for_each(begin, end, [this](decltype(*begin)& point) {
        mInternal.doSomething(point);
    }
}
```

or write the simple loop:

```
template <Iterator>
void doSomethingWithObjects(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
        mInternal.doSomething(*begin);
    }
}
```